# Split a string with multiple delimiter & create a separate list

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

I have a python string that contains a list of words separated by either a plus or minus sign

```
s = "AA + BB + 1C - CC - DD"
```

I want to get a list of words with a plus sign which is below

```
plusList = ["AA", "BB", "1C"]
```

And a list with a minus sign as below

```
minusList = ["CC", "DD"]
```

Any help appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
import re

s = "AA + BB + 1C - CC - DD"

plusList = re.findall(r"(?:^|\+\s*)(\w+)", s)
minusList = re.findall(r"(?:\-\s*)(\w+)", s)

print(plusList)
print(minusList)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```